# Grails update one to many through parent domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have domain objects similar to the following scenario

```
Author{
    Long id
    static hasMany = [
        autthorBook: AuthorBook
    ]
}

Book{
    Long id
}

AuthorBook{
   Long id
   Book book
   Author author
   static belongsTo = Author

   static mapping = {
    book column: 'book_id'
    author column: 'authod_id'
    version false
   }
}
```

During update, I get the Author id and a set of Book id's. How can I update Author without checking manually if that AuthorBook exist, or if existed AuthorBook was removed. I require a method at which, at the end when the line

```
Author.save()
```

is executed (Where Author would have a list of new AuthorBook which has no id) to update the AuthorBook table, removing AuthorBook entries which no longer exist, and add new entries if needed without a manual check of looping through each existing entry.

Comment: Unrelated - don't bother adding `Long id` properties to domain classes. Grails already does that for you during compilation.

Comment: Have you considered using a many-to-many between Author and Book? It's essentially what you're doing except GORM can do some of the work for you. In other words, it would simplify things.

Comment: I have considered that. But For my requirement, the structure has to be similar to this. So I cannot have the many-to-many relationship between author and book